# Running Android apps on iOS

Tags: ios, emulator

I am looking for an iOS program than can allow to run Android applications on iOS 7.1. If possible, free and no need to jailbreak.

Comment: Bonus points if such a programs proves that P != NP automatically. ;-)

Comment: Worth a read potentially.. http://theappforpc.com/2015/09/download-run-android-apps-on-ios/ / http://www.technonutty.com/2015/06/how-to-download-run-android-apps-on-ios.html

Answer (score 1):

Also a longshot and not exactly what the OP requested, but [SVMP](https://svmp.github.io/) might be the way to do this.

This would run virtual devices in the cloud that you should be able to access remotely from another Android or iOS device.

It's open-source and I'm expecting no special permissions would be needed on the end user's physical devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is a longshot. The only thing that came to my mind - not tried - and it would probably be unstable, breaking all the time...

1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing to a machine...

2) ...that runs Android VM

Or RDP / VNC directly to Android.

---

Not sure, not tried, would be fun to fiddle with it :)

Comment: Wouldn't that require the OP to have an Android device to remote into? What if he has only an iOs device?